# Why does calling .Clear() load the related entities?

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have a pretty basic EF model that has Orders and Order Line Items.  In the process of doing a final save, where I actually write the order with the line items to the database, I call Order.OrderItems.Clear() before adding in the order items that come from a session variable.  For the most part, this code works fine.  But every now and then, I get an error email (errors are caught and sent to me) with the following stack trace:

```
The ObjectContext instance has been disposed and can no longer be used for operations that require a connection.   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.EnsureConnection()
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.GetResults(Nullable`1 forMergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery`1.Execute(MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(List`1 collection, MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Load(MergeOption mergeOption)
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.Load()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.RelatedEnd.DeferredLoad()
   at System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.EntityCollection`1.Clear()
   at UserRegistration.Models.SaveRepository.SaveOrder(Order order)
```

I understand object contexts and why it is disposed (I have since disabled lazy loading on my EF model to hopefully prevent this in the future) but why does EF do a load after doing a clear?

Comment: The stack trace is very incomplete, this quacks like a threading bug.

Comment: It's a .NET MVC application.  I take the order out of the session and eventually call save on the repository.  I'm not using multi-threading that I know of.  Where else can I look for a fuller stack trace?